# how to make one div float over other

Tags: jquery, css

```
   <div>
   <a href="">
    <img src="images/fifa.jpg" /></a>

    </div>
 <div class="wrapper">

   <h4>Like Football</h4>
    <p class="wrappercontent">
   <span>Download FIFA 12 on Xperia™!</span>
    <a href="" onclick=""><span>Find more</span></a>
   </p>

   </div>
```

CSS

```
   .wrapper
    {
        background-color:Black;
        color:White;
        width:240px;
        height:70px;
         margin-top:-50px;
         position:absolute;

    }
    .wrappercontent
    {
         display: none;
    }
```

**jquery**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {


       $(".wrapper").hover(function () {
        $(".wrappercontent").show();


       });
```

When i hover the wrapper div p tag content are not shown

I want to make a functionality like [enter link description here](http://www.sonyericsson.com/cws/cws/home?cc=us&lc=e)

I the link when we hover on like football the div expands

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a very basic mimic of the sony ericson site;

```
<div id="big_image">
  <img src="..." />
  <div id="floats_holder">
    <div class="float_over">
      Americas, etc
      <div class="hidden_for_hover">
        some countries
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float_over">
      Asias, etc
      <div class="hidden_for_hover">
        more countries
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
#big_image { position:relative; } /* so we can use absolute on inner contents */
#floats_holder { position:absolute; top:100px; left:0; width:100%; }
.float_over { float:left; margin-left:20px; }
.float_over .hidden_for_hover { display:none; position:absolute; bottom:0; }
```

and the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".float_over").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.hidden_for_hover').slideDown();
  }, function(){
    $(this).find('.hidden_for_hover').slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: which part of the action are you looking for? that the div moves down towards to countries list, that the countries list appears? nothing is really expanding there- one thing uses the jquery animate{} to move down, the other just uses fadein(). Maybe you can rephrase...

Answer (score 0):

i believe setting the right position and z-index could do it.

For example try to set

```
.wrappercontent
{
  position: absolute;
  width:240px;
  height:70px;    
  z-index: 9001;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".wrappercontent").hide();

         $(".wrapper").hover(function () {
            $(".wrappercontent").show();});

    });
```

remove

```
.wrappercontent
    {
         display: none;
    }
```